# How to add [t] option to column export to beamer in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, beamer

how do I tell org-mode to include the [t] option in a column in a beamer presentation?

I need the following exported code:

```
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
```

so far I have tried:

```
*** columna izq
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BEAMER_col: 0.45
  :BEAMER_envargs: [t]
  :END:
```

but it does not seem to work. I have checked http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/ox-beamer.html but failed to find the solution.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... using BEAMER_envargs is for the old exporter. BEAMER_opt should be
recognized by the new exporter.

You could be interested by my "refcard" (still work in progress, though), available on https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer.

Comment: Thanks! I failed to find the option in the new exporter. And thank you also for the refcard!

Comment: [Beamer export docs in the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-export.html#Beamer-export)